# c# winforms get lowest controls (colored pictureboxes) from IList<Control> in tablelayout

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, tetris

Hey I'd like to know how I could figure out the lowest squares of an IList in a table layout panel. These elements are based on 2d multi-dimensional int arrays. I am planning to develop tetris, using a tablelayoutpanel with 10 rows and 10 columns and each cell contains a picturebox with the backcolor control and the backcolor changes when there will be dropped an element (tetromino) and its working fine so far, but I became a problem to figure out how elements collide. So far I made it to get the lowest square possible but not multiple ones. In the screenshot below you get a better view on what I mean. I have to determine the lowest squares of an element to check in an if clause if they collide to other elements.
[image: Multiple lower squares to determine]

By that, I already have made it to check what's the lowest possible square is looping each square of the IList containing all squares (Controls, in this case there are pictureboxes)
[image: Lowest square of element determined already]

Also here you get a screenshot of my 2d-array for the shape of the element itself:
[image: 2dimensional array]

Comment: [getrow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getrow?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Dear TaW, I have already used this method but my problem is I have to figure out the lowest squares of the tetromino

Comment: Well, from the image you show wouldn't that be the square(s) with the largest row number(s)?